# Circle Ci: Second job never runs?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

New to the world of CircleCI and cannot seem to get anything apart from the first job to run.

I've tried all sorts of things from removing line breaks to renaming the job to "test", swapping the order of the first job and the second job, but nothing works.

Is there something I need to change in the project config such as defining jobs ahead of time?

**.circleci/config.yml**

```
version: 2.0

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.5.0-node-browsers

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run:
          name: install bundler
          command: gem install bundler

      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            bundle install --jobs=4 --retry=3 --path vendor/bundle

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ./vendor/bundle
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}

  precompile_assets:
    machine: true

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - run:
          name: Precompile assets for public folder
          command: rails assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

*disclaimer: Developer Evangelist at CircleCI*

You're missing the Workflows section of the config. The part that tells CircleCI which jobs are available and how to run them.

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/

Also, the `precompile_assets` job will fail because it doesn't have any files from your repo. You'd need to have a checkout, or utilize `workspaces` (also available in my link above) in order to provide it files.